# Big Query: Find number of characters in a column which are contained in a list

Tags: string, google-bigquery, find

For each row in the example string-formatted column below,

| Response |
| --- |
| A |
| A, B |
| A, C |
| B, C |
| A, C, D |
| A, B, E |

I want to find the number of characters which are contained in the list (A, C, E).

I expectant the resultant column to be

| Result |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

How can I achieve this using SQL, specifically, through Big Query?

Effectively, I want to count the number of characters which form an intersection of the Response column and the list, excluding the commas.

Will be grateful for any responses!

Comment: HI, you can try subtracting the length of the whole line with the length of the line from which you removed the 3 characters, e.g. with a REPLACE(). In this way you should find the occurrences of the characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method, as I wrote in the comments:

```
SELECT 
    COLUMN_NAME,
    LENGTH(COLUMN_NAME) - LENGTH(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(COLUMN_NAME, 'A', ''), 'C', ''), 'E', '')) AS CharacterCount
FROM 
    TABLE_NAME;
```